# Ruby Regex Match Multiple variable from a single string

Tags: ruby, regex

Fairly new to ruby. I'm trying to parse a string and assign several variables with a regex.

I've consulted the docs, Googled a bit, and pretty sure that the following should work.

```
@operating_system, @os_update, @os_arch = @version_line[0].match(
        /(Solaris \d+)\s+\d+\/\d+\ss\d+[sx]_u(\d+)\wos_\d+\w+\s+(\w+)$/
        )
```

Where `@version_line = [" Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 s10x_u9wos_14a X86\n"]`

But all that happens is my first variable, @operating_system is assigned `Solaris 10 9/10 s10x_u9wos_14a X86`

Am I trying to do it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `match` returns a `MatchData` object, which happens to have a `to_s` method that produces the string you see.

To get all matched capture groups as an array, use the `captures` method:

```
@operating_system, @os_update, @os_arch = @version_line[0].match(
        /(Solaris \d+)\s+\d+\/\d+\ss\d+[sx]_u(\d+)\wos_\d+\w+\s+(\w+)$/
        ).captures
```

Comment: strange… `String#match` works for me. It's in the docs for 1.8.7 as well as 1.9.1 and 1.9.3

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Thomas I totally missed the fact that match returned MatchData object!

Comment: You were right about @version_line = ["..."], I'll edit my question.

Comment: Yeah, I have it too. Just not on `Array` ;)

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(Solaris \d+)\s+\d+/\d+\s\w+\s\w+`